# Equivalent of Guava's Preconditions.checkNotNull(...) for Objective-C?

Tags: java, objective-c, guava

In Java, I like to start methods with using [Guava's Preconditions class](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html) to make sure the method parameters are not null, or are valid values. For example:

```
public void myMethod(String str) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(str);
    ... method logic here ...
}
```

This is an important part of my approach to coding. Is there something similar in Objective-C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent is NSParameterAssert, defined in NSException.h.  It's not as full-featured as Guava's, though.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with assert()? I.e. assert(str!=nil);

Comment: If I understand, assert is removed from compiled production code. I want these checks all the time, to catch any error in use by the client code.

Comment: Also, static analysis can sometimes do a better job when given specific assertions about parameter preconditions.  No idea if that's true yet for anything from Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C is a superset of C, so you might find the following solution would fit your needs:
[Design by Contract in C](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2004/10/28/design_by_contract_in_c.html).  Another solution, using Objective-C, is described here: [A few Macros for Designing by Contract in Objective-C](http://www.roard.com/contracts/)